# Sublime Text 2 - SublimeREPL package issue

Tags: python, package, sublimetext, sublimerepl

Basically, I've installed Sublime Text 2 to write in Python.

I then installed Package control and via package control I search "SublimeREPL" and I install the package, however even after installing, when I select Python through Tools > SublimeREPL > Python > Python, I get the error:

WindowsError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.')

Any help please? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: You probably need to set your python path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `preferences -> Keybindings - User`
and paste this. Make sure there are only one set of `[]` in your file, if you have custom keybinds set already then add a `,` after your last `}` then paste everything but the `[]` at the beginning and end after your `,`.

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+r"], "command": "repl_open", 
                 "caption": "Python",
                 "mnemonic": "p",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "encoding": "utf8",
                    "cmd": ["python", "-i", "-u","$file"],
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "syntax": "Packages/Python/Python.tmLanguage",
                    "external_id": "python"
                    } 
    }
]
```

Save and quit Sublime Text.

Follow these instructions
[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)

You should now be able to run your current file in repl with crtl+shift+r

Open sublime text and create a new file. Save it as `hello.py`

Type:

```
print('Hello World')
```

Save then hit ctrl-shift-r

See if that works

Comment: Open your command line and type `python` hit enter. Does it start the python interpreter? It should show something like `>>>`. If not you didn't set your python path properly.

Comment: I get "'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: The problem is your python path, not anything to do with sublime. Do you have a directory ` C:\Python27\`? Or another folder named Python something, depending on your version.

Comment: Yes, I have C:\Python27

Comment: Try opening powershell and running: `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\", "User")`